# How to solve "nodemon" not recognized error?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

In vs code, I am creating a chat app but when I am entering nodemon and then file name it's showing "nodemon" not recognized. How to solve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YJ0J.jpg) error ?

Comment: Did you install `nodemon` as a dev dependency package? Did you add `"nodemon": "nodemon"` in `scripts` section of `package.json`? If so try `npm run nodemon`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure npm is install correctly (https://nodejs.org/en/), then download the dependency you want to use, since you want to use "nodemon", you need to get the package.

Open terminal/cmd on the root directory for the app, (Same location of package.json)

`npm install -g nodemon`

-g = install package globally

without -g = will only install package in project

if you want to add this dependency to your package.json use:

`npm install nodemon --save-dev`

always a good idea to read the documentation of the library you want to use,
they usually have great examples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Best of luck on your journey!

Answer (score 0):

this is a short-hand trick, not highly recommended but will solve the issue for the time being.
if even after globally installing it using `**npm install -g nodemon**`
and refreshing VS, it doesn't work just create a script out of it in the following way-

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon <js file name>"
  }
```

and then execute it from the terminal-
npm run dev